# How to insert a row into table automatically?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have two tables (parent & child) in my database. How can I insert a new record into the parent table so that a record is automatically inserted into child table?

Comment: Why, what is your real life situation? What speaks against inserting both rows explicitly? What platform are you using mySQL from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use (after insert) triggers for that, see [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) for syntax.

Comment: Does **Trigger** insert a record into child automatically? OP's Question - How can i insert a new record into Parent table so that record should **automatically** inserted into Child table?

Comment: You can have `INSERT` statement in the trigger, no? As I understand the OP, he wants to add record into "detail table" when record is inserted into "master table". So write an after insert trigger for the master, You have the PK of the master in the trigger so inserting into details is easy...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using a trigger to insert a new child record with the just-generated parent auto-increment id.

```
mysql> create table ParentTable (id int auto_increment primary key);

mysql> create table ChildTable (id int auto_increment primary key,
       parentId int, foreign key (parentId) references ParentTable(id));

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger AFTER INSERT ON ParentTable
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> INSERT INTO ChildTable (parentId) VALUES (NEW.id);

mysql> insert into ParentTable () values ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from ChildTable;
+----+----------+
| id | parentId |
+----+----------+
|  1 |        1 |
+----+----------+
```

This is a trivial example, because the two tables don't have any other columns except for their primary keys and the foreign key.

But what if you want to insert other columns into the child table?

The trigger only has access to the `NEW.*` columns of the row it just inserted into the parent. It may also `SELECT` other existing data from elsewhere in the database. Or it could use hard-coded literal values.

There may also be defaults on the other columns in the child table, or else it may be okay for them to be NULL temporarily, until you can fill them in with subsequent UPDATE statements.

You have to accept that the trigger might not be able to give specific values for the relevant columns as it INSERTs to the child table.